# How do I Call Functions on a Parent Class's Ancestor Object?

Tags: python, django

Given the below cut down headache of a function, how would I go about calling a function on the utils.PrintingTemplateBase object that PrintingTemplate is inheriting?

I would also mention that PrintingTemplateBase requires an instance of itself to use (the closest being PrintingTemplate)

```
class PrintingTemplate (utils.PrintingTemplateBase) :

    #  Class used to accumulate lines of data
    #
    class LineData :

        #  Class constructor, optionally passed an existing instance in which case
        #  data is copied.
        #
        def __init__ (self, data = None) :

            self.number_of_panes            = 0
            self.material                   = ''  


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #
    #  LineData subclass for data coming from CalcGlass
    #
    class LineDataGlass (LineData) :

        def __init__ (self, calc_glass) :

            self.number_of_panes           = calc_glass.calc_component.calc_subitem.item.quantity
            try     : self.material        = calc_glass.glass_unit.workshop_description
            except  : self.material        = 'Undefined glass'


    def __init__(self) :

        utils.PrintingTemplateBase.__init__ (self)
        self.constants      = None
```

Comment: Please show an example of a method you're trying to call. What do the two LineData classes have to do with anything? Why are you creating them inside the PrintingTemplate class? There's almost never a good reason to do that in Python.

Comment: well, from inside PrintingTemplate I can call `self.decimal0(var)` and it'll return an formatted float to 0sf. but now i want to be able to do that from inside LineDataGlass.

Comment: as for why? An old school programmer i've inherited from, very technically clever guy, almost impossible to follow his code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python is not Java.

In Python, declaring a class inside another class does not give it any special access to the parent class. That's why I said there's almost never a good reason to do this.

If you need a LineData instance to have access to a PrintingTemplate instance, you'll need to give it a reference to that instance, either by passing it into the `__init__` method or by instantiating one directly there.